# What is the correct way to send datetime from Angular to Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, time, angular5

I am using primeng calendar in a template driven form. When I pass `16/05/2018 11:45` from angular to node. It gets converted to
 `2018-05-16T06:15:33.000Z`.

I have found that I can convert it back to IST time by

`new Date(req.body.BIDInstalledFrom.toLocaleString("en-ind",{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'}));`

But this does not seem to the correct/recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

This will always happen when Timezone between client and server is different or not determined.

I mostly solve issues like this by transmitting a timestamp which requires some different handling on the client.

For **prime-ng callendar** it can be configured via the `dateFormat` property on **callendar** element

```
<!-- dateFormat="@" provides a timestamp -->
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" dateFormat="@"></p-calendar>
```

Copied from [primeng documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar):

**Following options can be a part of the format.**

- d - day of month (no leading zero)
- dd - day of month (two digit)
- o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
- oo - day of the year (three digit)
- D - day name short
- DD - day name long
- m - month of year (no leading zero)
- mm - month of year (two digit)
- M - month name short
- MM - month name long
- y - year (two digit)
- yy - year (four digit)
- @ **- Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)**
- ! - Windows ticks (100ns since 01/01/0001)
- '...' - literal text
- '' - single quote

Comment: problem with `prime-ng callendar` 's @ unix timestamp is that when you select a date in calendar it shows timestamp in the textbox. I want textbox to display dd/mm/yyyy but convert it to timestamp when creating json and similarly convert timestamp to dd/mm/yyyy when showing  date from component to view